# Should GitHub be used during development of a website?

Tags: github

I am currently developing a website using html, css, php, and javascript. During this development, I am constantly modifying the css to get just the right look.

I feel that it is impractical to re-upload files or modify them all on GitHub as I continue this development. Am I right that I think that GitHub should be used near the ending stages of development, or is there some functionality of GitHub I do not yet know?

Comment: The whole reason behind why you should be using git is for version control. You commit files as a snapshot that you can return to at any point in history. There's no need to constantly re-upload the modified files onto Github each time, by pushing your changes. You can merely commit the changes to save that point in history, and push the commits at any point thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

Github (and git in general) can be helpful in the development of a website, but it really depends on your needs. In your case, you mention CSS. If you manage to ruin your CSS beyond repair, then git has your back, since you can revert back to a working version. Github makes this easier by allowing you to directly see the CSS file with all insertions and deletions.

If your content does not undergo drastic changes, and you make occasional smaller changes, then git should work well. Version control is the main goal of git, and since small changes to a file don't involve a brand new copy of the file but rather the inserted and deleted lines, there may be an advantage to using git rather than backing up your entire website every now and then.

So in the end, it depends on what your website is like and how you plan to tweak/update it.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why it should not be. The so-called *development stage* of any project is (should be?) especially messy. Although the benefits of version control is not apparent during this stage, they can not be stressed enough because of its ability

1. to "go back" in time,
2. to provide a sensible, repeatable, dependable work environment
3. to lead into a development process that you can rely upon.

A [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is also required. This, coupled with a quick and easy devops procedure (which works so well with git) should also be employed from day 1.

When I did my website development, I used git extensively (although not GitHub), and since GitHub has excellent support for private repos, there is no reason not to use it. You could also take a look at [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) which creates websites from your repos!

Comment: Thanks! Also, since you mentioned using Git for the process, what is the difference between both Git and GitHub?

Comment: Git is a (distributed) version control system. GitHub is a provider of such a system. The former is a piece of software, the latter provides that software (and much more) as a service.